# booleans default to false when getting value from a different class

Tags: android

when i try to get a true/false value from a different class it seems that it is defaulting to false. here are the snippets of my code that should be the problem. the first snippet is the class i'm getting the values from, the second one is the one that is requesting that information. and at the bottom of the second class is the function that should make the class render on the apps screen but seems to not work at all every time. you should be able to understand my coding cause i practice the art of commenting profusely.

```
private boolean AddProb;
private boolean SubProb;
private boolean MultiProb;
private boolean DivisProb;

public int ANum = 0;
public int SNum;
public int MNum;
public int DNum;

//ProblemSelector PS = new ProblemSelector();

CheckBox checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problem_selector);

    checkbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkbox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkbox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    checkbox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

    /** waits for checkbox1 to be clicked then triggers the arguments below it **/
    /** also sets the lists position if the other problems for training have been selected to practice **/
    checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                AddProb = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Addition: True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Addition: True");
                if(AddProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","AddProb did successfully change to true");
                } else if(!AddProb){
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","AddProb did not successfully change to true");
                } else {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 50-56");
                }
            } else {
                AddProb = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Addition: False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Addition: False");
                if(AddProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","AddProb did successfully change to false");
                } else if(!AddProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","AddProb did not successfully change to false");
                } else {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 61-67");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /** waits for checkbox2 to be clicked then triggers the arguments below it **/
    /** also sets the lists position if the other problems for training have been selected to practice **/
    checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                SubProb = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Subtraction: True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Subtraction: True");
                if(SubProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","SubProb did successfully change to true");
                } else if(!SubProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","SubProb did not successfully change to true");
                } else {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 82-88");
                }
                if(AddProb == false) {
                    SNum = 0;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true) {
                    SNum = 1;
                }
            } else {
                SubProb = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Subtraction: False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Subtraction: False");
                if(SubProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","SubProb did successfully change to false");
                } else if(!SubProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","SubProb did not successfully change to false");
                } else {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 99-105");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /** waits for checkbox3 to be clicked then triggers the arguments below it **/
    /** also sets the lists position if the other problems for training have been selected to practice **/
    checkbox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                MultiProb = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Multiplication: True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Multiplication: True");
                if(MultiProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","MultiProb did successfully change to true");
                } else if(!MultiProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","MultiProb did not successfully change to true");
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 120-126");
                }
                if(AddProb == false && SubProb == false) {
                    MNum = 0;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true && SubProb == false || AddProb == false && SubProb == true) {
                    MNum = 1;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true && SubProb == true) {
                    MNum = 2;
                }
            } else {
                MultiProb = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Multiplication: False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Multiplication: False");
                if(MultiProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","MultiProb did successfully change to false");
                } else if(!MultiProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","MultiProb did not successfully change to false");
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 140-146");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /** waits for checkbox4 to be clicked then triggers the arguments below it **/
    /** also sets the lists position if the other problems for training have been selected to practice **/
    /** and determines if the value of the boolean for this function has changed successfully or not **/
    checkbox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                DivisProb = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Division: True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Division: True");
                if(DivisProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","DivisProb did successfully change to true");
                } else if(!DivisProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","DivisProb did not successfully change to true");
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 162-168");
                }
                if(AddProb == false && SubProb == false && MultiProb == false) {
                    DNum = 0;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true && SubProb == false && MultiProb == false || AddProb == false && SubProb == true && MultiProb == false || AddProb == false && SubProb == false && MultiProb == true) {
                    DNum = 1;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true && SubProb == true && MultiProb == false || AddProb == false && SubProb == true && MultiProb == true || AddProb == true && SubProb == false && MultiProb == true) {
                    DNum = 2;
                }
                else if(AddProb == true && SubProb == true && MultiProb == true) {
                    DNum = 3;
                }
            } else {
                DivisProb = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Division: False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Division: False");
                if(DivisProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","DivisProb did successfully change to false");
                } else if(!DivisProb) {
                    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","DivisProb did not successfully change to false");
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProblemSelector.java","Something went horribly wrong at line: 184-189");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_problem_selector, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** this is called when the user hits the continue button **/
public void DifficultyMenu(View view) {
    String S1 = String.valueOf(AddProb);
    Log.d("ProblemSelector.java","AddProb: " + S1);
    Intent DifficultyView = new Intent(this, DifficultyMenu.class);
    //DifficultyView.putExtra("addProb", PS.AddProb);
    //DifficultyView.putExtra("subProb", PS.SubProb);
    //DifficultyView.putExtra("multiProb", PS.MultiProb);
    //DifficultyView.putExtra("divisProb", PS.DivisProb);
    startActivity(DifficultyView);
}

/** this converts the 1st version bools to 2nd version bools and outputs the values to the command line **/
public boolean AddP = AddProb;
public boolean SubP = SubProb;
public boolean MultiP = MultiProb;
public boolean DivisP = DivisProb;
}
```

here is the second class.

```
private boolean AddP = PS.AddP;
private boolean SubP = PS.SubP;
private boolean MultiP = PS.MultiP;
private boolean DivisP = PS.DivisP;

private int ANum = PS.ANum;
private int SNum = PS.SNum;
private int MNum = PS.MNum;
private int DNum = PS.DNum;

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_difficulty_menu);

    // here you'll retrieve the data sent...you can google how to do that.

    // get the list view
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // List view Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // List view Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // List view Group collapsed listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // List view on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            /** converts the selected number in the expandable list to a usable integer variable **/
            /** also detects if a Difficulty has been selected for each for of problem to practice **/
            /** also gives an error to debug console level if something unexpected has happened **/
            if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("AdditionDifficulty")) {
                String St1 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int AddDiff = Integer.parseInt(St1);
                if(PS.AddP) {
                    AChecked = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("DifficultyMenu.java","Somehow got to line: 123 : for some reason this seems to have happened");
                }
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("SubtractionDifficulty")) {
                String St2 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int SubDiff = Integer.parseInt(St2);
                if(PS.SubP) {
                    SChecked = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("DifficultyMenu.java","Somehow got to line: 132 : for some reason this seems to have happened");
                }
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("MultiplicationDifficulty")) {
                String St3 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int MultiDIff = Integer.parseInt(St3);
                if(PS.MultiP) {
                    MChecked = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("DifficultyMenu.java","Somehow got to line: 141 : for some reason this seems to have happened");
                }
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("DivisionDifficulty")) {
                String St4 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int DivisDiff = Integer.parseInt(St4);
                if(PS.DivisP) {
                    DChecked = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("DifficultyMenu.java","Somehow got to line: 150 : for some reason this seems to have happened");
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("DifficultyMenu.java","could not parse a group position when user selected a field");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    // Adding child data
    if(AddP) { listDataHeader.add("AdditionDifficulty"); }
    if(SubP) { listDataHeader.add("SubtractionDifficulty"); }
    if(MultiP) { listDataHeader.add("MultiplicationDifficulty"); }
    if(DivisP) { listDataHeader.add("DivisionDifficulty"); }
    System.out.println(listDataHeader);
    /** this removes fields that the user has not selected to practice **/
//        if(!PS.AddProb) { listDataHeader.remove("AdditionDifficulty"); }
//        if(!PS.SubProb) { listDataHeader.remove("SubtractionDifficulty"); }
//        if(!PS.MultiProb) { listDataHeader.remove("MultiplicationDifficulty"); }
//        if(!PS.DivisProb) { listDataHeader.remove("DivisionDifficulty"); }

    // Adding child data
    List<String> AdditionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T1 < 11) {
            String S1 = Integer.toString(T1);
            AdditionDifficulty.add(S1);
            T1++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> SubtractionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T2 < 11) {
            String S2 = Integer.toString(T2);
            SubtractionDifficulty.add(S2);
            T2++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> MultiplicationDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T3 < 11) {
            String S3 = Integer.toString(T3);
            MultiplicationDifficulty.add(S3);
            T3++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> DivisionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T4 < 11) {
            String S4 = Integer.toString(T4);
            DivisionDifficulty.add(S4);
            T4++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    /** this draws out the Expandable lists **/
    if(AddP) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(ANum), AdditionDifficulty);
    } else {
        Log.d("DifficultyMenu.java","Something went wrong at line: 230");
    }
    if(SubP) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(SNum), SubtractionDifficulty);
    } else {
        Log.d("DifficultyMenu.java","Something went wrong at line: 231");
    }
    if(MultiP) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(MNum), MultiplicationDifficulty);
    } else {Log.d("DifficultyMenu.java","Something went wrong at line: 232");
    }
    if(DivisP) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(DNum), DivisionDifficulty);
    } else {Log.d("DifficultyMenu.java","Something went wrong at line: 233");
    }
}
```

Comment: boolean default value is false..

Comment: which is your PS (ProblemSelector) class are you holding static instance of variables

Comment: the PS class is the first one

Comment: please give us only  "[the shortest code necessary to reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) " your problem, which means leave out three of the checkboxes and - as you're experiencing difficulties with passing values from one class to the other - please add to your code how you did that.